# Angular application loses styling and javascript when browser refreshed (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working on my first Angular.js application and it is working well, but I am continually having two problems with refreshing of the browser. I have attached a link to a screencast that shows the problem. The two problems are:

1. When I hit the refresh button or ctrl-f5, the page loses all CSS styling.
2. When I click the "calendar" link to return to the home page, things like the username show when they should not. Have a look at the screencast here: [Problem on screencast](http://screencast.com/t/wiZlJusV)

Here is my routing:

```
'use strict';

var JBenchApp = angular.module('JBenchApp', [
    'ngRoute'
]);

JBenchApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'JBenchCtrl'
        }).
        when('/calendar', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/calendar.html',
            controller: 'JBenchCtrl'
        }).
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/calendar.html',
            controller: 'JBenchCtrl'
        }).
        when('/documents/:number', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/documents.html',
            controller: 'CaseDetailCtrl'
        }).
        when('/parties/:number', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/parties.html',
              controller: 'CaseDetailCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/calendar'
        });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  }]);
```

EDIT TO ADD web.config FILE PART:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
            <rewriteMaps>
                <rewriteMap name="/JWB/" />
            </rewriteMaps>
  </rewrite>
```

Any idea how to make this issue go away?

Comment: Are you getting any console log errors?

Comment: yes, it appears it cannot see the javascript files for angular and for jquery

Comment: sounds like you need a base tag, or absolute urls for your assets. Relative urls are relative to the page path at the time the page loaded. When you go to example.com/, then navigate to example.com/admin, then refresh, it's as if you navigated to example.com/admin directly so all relative urls will now point to /admin instead of / unless you have a base tag.

Comment: I have the base tag and as you can see, when the application loads everything is fine. It isn't untl doing a refresh that the issue arises

Comment: Close your browser. now, reopen it, and instead of typing in `http://myapp.com`, type in `http://myapp.com/somepath/`. You will see that the assets also don't load there. Reloading isn't the problem, it's the path the browser is using to resolve the assets.

Comment: The path the browser uses to resolve the assets is based on the url used to get to the asset, and, if that url is relative, the base tag. so, something is likely wrong with your base tag.

Comment: Kevin, put through an answer because based upon your comment (while not entirely correct), I changed "js/angular.min.js" to "../js/angular.min.js" and it worked

Comment: Does it also work if you now navigate directly tot he root of your app and refresh? i suspect it will break.

Comment: nope it also works that way because ../ says to start at the root of the applicaiton, so application/calendar will work, application will work, application/parties/989-99a will work because the ../ will force me back to the root of the application

Comment: ../ actually says to go back 1 folder in the path. so, from /some/path/ to /some/ for example. so if you have states nested deeper than one, you'll run into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because to the browser, you're now requesting a page at **/some/path/**, and if you have any relative urls in your asset paths, the browser will look for them at **/some/path/js/foo.js** instead of **/js/foo.js**.

There are several ways to fix this, but, the easiest is likely to just use absolute paths.

```
src="/js/foo.js"
```

Sometimes however this won't work due to hosting the application within a subfolder of a domain. In that case, a base tag might be more appropriate.

```
<base href="/subfolder/">
```

Comment: I have a base tag in there now, but since it is running root the tag is set to "/" yet the JS files still were loading incorrectly. As stated, I fixed this by adding "../" in front of all JS and CSS file paths.

Comment: `application/parties/989-99a` shouldn't work with `../`, it'l look for files in `application/parties/js/foo.js`

Comment: It works perfectly. As you will see in the screencast below, I do not yet have it holding onto the logged in status, but watch what happens. http://screencast.com/t/d5GoPHrs

Comment: Post it as an answer if you wish, i don't think that should work, so i'm not making it part of my answer.

Comment: Actually, when NOT off the route (ie. http://server/jwb/) if I refresh any page I get a 404 on that page. It is not the javascript and CSS that is an issue at thsi point, the site cannot find the url http://server/jwb/parties/12345 for instance. However, it goes there initially and loads the file. The routing is above so what could be causing this?

Comment: the routing that would be causing that problem is server-side i think, not angular routing. Or did you mean it's loading angular fine, but angular is giving you the calendar page instead.

Comment: Angular loads fine and so do all pages until I hit refresh and then I get a 404 error. See this screencaset: http://screencast.com/t/WlgB2tCotm

Comment: then yes, it's a server problem. When you refresh, you're requesting that page from the server, where as if you navigate there from angular that isn't happening at all.

Comment: Right...so then the possibility is it is the rewrite rule in the web.config? See code added to the question above.

Comment: Looks right to me, but, i'm not that great at writing those myself, so i may be missing something too.